# SSL call from Spring Boot using feign client

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, feign

It's first time when I am trying to configure keys for a secure call. I have a pair of private and public keys for an endpoint and I don't know how to configure it using Spring boot with Feign client.

I tried adding the keys in the keystore but the private key didn’t work. Can you help me figure out how to import certificates to my spring boot app?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpringBoot: FeignClient with SSL (p12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853829/springboot-feignclient-with-ssl-p12)

Comment: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html

Comment: Clarify what you mean with "but the private key didn't work". Did you get an error somewhere? Post all relevant code and configuration here for others to reproduce.